# How to find the volume?

Tags: calculus

Find the volume V of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified line.
$y = 8x^3, y = 0, x = 1$;    about $x = 2$

I understand that you have to use the washer method to find the volume. the formula is integral $\pi R^2-\pi r^2$

Answer (score 1):

Given rotation about $x=2$ with $y=8x^3,y=0,x=1$

The rotation line $x=2$ is a vertical line, then the cross-sectional area $A$ will be expressed in terms of $y$ and thus we need to rewrite the given equations in terms of $y$.

$y=8x^3\implies x=\dfrac12y^{\frac13}$

When you make a graph, you will note that $x=1$ lies closer to the rotation line than $y=8x^3$ and thus the inner radius will corresponds with $x=1$, while the outer radius corresponds with $y=8x^3$

So, the inner radius $=2-1=1$ and the outer radius $=2-\dfrac12y^{\frac13}$

Now the area is $A(y)=\pi\left[\left(2-\dfrac12y^{\frac13}\right)^2-(1)^2\right]$

When you draw the graph you notice that are has $y$- values from $0$ to $8$

So, the Volume is $$V=\int_0^8A(y)dy$$
$$V=\pi\int_0^8\left[3-2y^{\frac13}+\dfrac14y^{\frac23}\right]dy$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture and it becomes very easy.

Because the boundary is $x=1$, $2-1=1$, so little $r$ is $1$.
Now, big $R$ is is the distance from $x=2$ to $y=8x^3$.

$X=(\frac{y}{8})^{1/3}$
So the distance from $2$ to this function of $x$ is $2-(y/8)^{1/3}.$

So our integral is $\pi * \int_0^8 [(2-(y/8)^{1/3})^2-1] dy$